# Why is cell phone reverse lookup still so impoverished?

Tags: privacy

Often you get a call from a non-business number and your phone's filter app doesn't know who it might be. You might Google it, and find a thousand sites promising to tell you its owner, but they only have placeholders.

This is kind of surprising to me. With the amount of data leaking and unconscionable data sharing with third parties by half the sites you give your number to, doesn't it seem likely that a large proportion of numbers would have names attached to them?

Don't get me wrong — I'm not advocating for this kind of loss of privacy. I'm just curious how it is that the number-owner mapping has remained relatively obscure. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: good question, given that every mobile carrier requires ID registration for all personal SIM cards in pretty much all countries. If there is a reverse look-up tool that can access mobile carriers' client records and registrations, i would think they would have to secure alot of international cooperations

Answer (score 1):

It's not obscure, it's been monitized. If you're willing to pay for the information it's generally available.

Comment: who is the google of *international* cell phone reverse look-up monetization?

Comment: @user610620 - There are many, here's one example:  https://www.reversephonecheck.com/resources/international_phone_search/reverse_international_phone_search.html

Comment: The point of the question is that there is only one google. u have just seemed to plucked out the first link you found and called it a monopoly

Comment: @user610620 - I did indeed just pluck the first link I found on *DuckDuckGo*, as I said there are many. I have no idea why you are insisting on a monoply?

Comment: why not? if someone wants to eat mcdonalds, they dont go to wendys